# MVC Html.AntiForgeryToken() causing page to not load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, antiforgerytoken

We have a MVC web application where on multiple pages (Jobs & Units), there is a Delete link that opens a modal popup and prompts the user if they want to delete the record or not.

In this section of code we have the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() call but for some reason when we try to load the Jobs page, it returns a 504 error and the page fails to load but the Units page loads fine.

Also, this only happens on our Test servers which are on an F5 load balancer whereas on our Dev server, which is a single standalone server, it works fine.

If I comment out the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() line, the page will load like normal.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Also, is it absolutely necessary we have this on all our POST calls? I know it's standard but are there any downsides to not having it if that's the only way to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it may be because of the token itself see the token ss autometically created by iis so if you have restarted iis then the token gets changed which s basically a machine key i would say try using a static antiforgery token by setting it up on Web config

Comment: Are you using the same machine key on both servers in the load balancer?

Comment: I had tried adding the same machine key to both web.config's but that didn't resolve the issue either. 

Plus, why does the Units page load fine with the same code but not the Jobs page?

Comment: Not to mention, this was all working fine before yesterday. Would there have been something done to the F5 load balancer or something on the server that could cause this?